# Object getting converted to array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to update a [notification's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#database-notifications) data (for displaying it in a view):

```
$notifications = $user->notifications()->paginate(15);

foreach ($notifications as $notification)
{
    $post = Post::where('id', $notification->data['post_id'])
        ->first();
    $notification->data = $post;
}
```

But when I do this in my view:

```
@foreach ($notifications as $notification)
    {{ gettype($notification->data) }}
@endforeach
```

It shows that the data is an array. Why does it convert the `Post` model object to an array and how can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Rather than looping over the Notifications and querying the database each time to get the post, you should use relationships and eager loading. Then you could just do `$notification->post`.

Comment: Okay, using Laravel's notification system, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$notification` object is an instance of `Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification`. This is an Eloquent `Model` that has the following `$casts` property defined:

```
protected $casts = [
    'data' => 'array',
    'read_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

Because of this, when you access `$notification->data`, it will automatically be cast to an array.

To resolve your issue, and to reduce the number of database queries, you should just build a separate lookup collection of posts, and pass that into the view.

First, build an array of all the `Post` ids. Then, run one query to get all the `Post`|s for those ids. After that, re-key the resulting `Collection` of `Post`|s by the id for easy lookup later in the view. Make sure to pass your `Collection` of `Post`|s to the view.

```
$notifications = $user->notifications()->paginate(15);

$postIds = [];
foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
    $postIds[] = $notification->data['post_id'];
}

$posts = Post::whereIn('id', array_unique($postIds))->get()->keyBy('id');
```

Then, in your view:

```
@foreach ($notifications as $notification)
    {{ $posts->get($notification->data['post_id']) }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

You were not updating in $notifications that's why you are seeing old array not the new object you wanted to save.

```
foreach ($notifications as $key => $notification)
{
   $post = Post::where('id', $notification->data['post_id'])->first();
   $notifications[$key]->data = $post;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything. The output is still an array and not the `Post` model object.